# How to write an htaccess 301 Redirection rule to redirect from php to html

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a problem (it's probably a simple one but I've never had the need to write regex)

A SEO specialist told me to make pretty URLs so I did with the `.htaccess` file the CMS provides.
But now he requires me to redirect the old URLs to new ones.

This doesn't work

```
RewriteRule ^index.php?page=kontakt$ /kontakt.html  [R=301,L]
```

and also this (wich was supposed to redirect to the main page from the index.php file)

```
RewriteRule ^index.php$ /   [R=301,L]
```

has resulted in `sitename.com/?page=kontakt`, so now I also have to redirect this.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RewriteRule only matches the base URL without the query string. You need an additional RewriteCond for it to work.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=kontakt$
RewriteRule ^index.php$ /kontakt.html [R=301,L]
```

**EDIT:**
Apparently query string gets preserved in this case, so you're probably getting /kontakt.html?page=kontakt

To discard original query string you need to put `?` after URL.

```
RewriteRule ^index.php$ /kontakt.html? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but that gave me a strange result: 

**sitename.com/kontakt.html?page=kontakt**

is it possible it's something with the server settings?

Comment: It works, saved my life. I've been strugling with this for ages.
Thank you very much :D

Comment: One last thing, how can I also redirect `/?page=kontakt` without index.php file?

Comment: Simply use ^$ instead of ^index.php$